Is the depiction of a corrupt and murderous 16th-century ruler of Japan in "Shōgun" based on historical facts?
In the 2024 miniseries Shōgun (Season 1, Episode 5, "Broken to the Fist"), there's a scene where Lady Mariko reveals that she was the daughter of the late Lord Akechi Jinsai. She mentions that her father's lord was Lord Kuroda, who was apparently the ruler of Japan before the Taiko. According to Mariko, Kuroda was a corrupt and murderous ruler, so her father killed him out of love for the realm.
Now, this got me curious about how much of this storyline is based on real historical events. From what I understand, the character of the Taiko is based on the real-life figure of Toyotomi Hideyoshi, who was a powerful daimyo (feudal lord) in the late 16th century. And if I'm not mistaken, Oda Nobunaga was the ruler of Japan before Hideyoshi, which would make him the real-life equivalent of the character Kuroda in the show.
However, from my brief research on Wikipedia, I didn't find anything that suggested Oda Nobunaga was particularly corrupt or murderous, at least not more than what was (I think) considered normal for a warlord of that time period. As far as I can tell, he wasn't too different from Hideyoshi or Tokugawa Ieyasu (the real-life inspiration for one of the show's protagonists, Lord Yoshii Toranaga) in that regard.
Now, I'll be the first to admit that my knowledge of Japanese history is quite limited, and I haven't read the novel Shōgun by James Clavell, which the miniseries is based on. So, I'm wondering if any history buffs out there can shed some light on this.
Was any ruler of Japan in the 16th century actually seen as a corrupt and murderous figure in real life? If so, what were some of the specific corrupt or murderous actions that the ruler was known for? Or is this portrayal of Kuroda in the show purely fictitious, perhaps added for dramatic effect?

Nobunaga, for sure, was brutal. If killings were often the norm (necessary?), brutality isn't part of the Japanese culture in the way we (Europeans or possibly others) see it. Nobunaga not only humiliated people (and his father's soul) during his father's funeral, but he also later killed his brother. He relied on people because of their skills more than on their lineage. He defeated many clans/people. Because of these 3 things, he made lots of ennemies. Even if he committed seppuku, for literacy purposes, I suppose a writer can invent a 'right' man to kill him for the sake of humanity.

2/2 In the Japanese culture, image is one, if not the most, important part of life. There are rituals. Death is part of life, and isn't seen as we do.  "She describes to him the concept of the “eightfold fence,” a coping mechanism taught to young people in Japan that allows them to retreat, emotionally, into a walled-off area inside the self. “Do not be fooled by our politeness. Our bows, our rituals. Beneath it all we can be a great distance away. Safe and alone." Nobunaga made many violations of the japanese spirit that upset many many people. Easy to find someone to get rid of him :)
